How do I make a mathematical object enter the scene from the top left of the screen using ManimCE?
I have tried several different methods including: .move_to(), .shift(), and .to_edge(UP + LEFT), but the sine wave I am animating keeps appearing at the center of the screen, and I need it to enter the scene from the top left of the screen and travel down towards the middle of the screen.
Here is what I have from a recent attempt:
from manim import *


class SineWave(Scene):
    def get_sine_wave(self, dx=0):
        return FunctionGraph(
            lambda x: np.sin(4*x + dx),
            x_range=[-2, 2]
        )

    def construct(self):
         sine_function = self.get_sine_wave()
        d_theta = ValueTracker(0)

        def update_wave(func):
            func.become(
                self.get_sine_wave(dx=d_theta.get_value())
            )
            return func
   
        sine_function.add_updater(update_wave)

        sine_function.shift(2*LEFT+ UP)
        self.add(sine_function)
    
        self.play(Create(sine_function))
        self.play(d_theta.animate.increment_value(4 * PI), rate_func=linear)
        self.wait()

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using the add_updater() function, you always override your move operations. Here is a solution, where I put this into the get_sine_wave() fct:
from manim import *

class SineWave(Scene):
    def get_sine_wave(self, dx=0):
        return FunctionGraph(lambda x: np.sin(4 * x + dx), x_range=[-2, 2]).to_edge(UL)

    def construct(self):
        sine_function = self.get_sine_wave()
        d_theta = ValueTracker(0)

        def update_wave(func):
            func.become(self.get_sine_wave(dx=d_theta.get_value()))
            return func

        sine_function.add_updater(update_wave)

        self.play(Create(sine_function))
        self.play(d_theta.animate.increment_value(4 * PI), rate_func=linear)
        self.wait()

Note that FunctionGraph is intended to use the whole length of the video, see doc. Also it is not necessary to add the sine_function before creating it.
